# Flash Game Help

Tags: flash, macos, download

What do I need to download to make flash games and how much does it cost? Also will I be able to use a mac to do this?

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/products/flash/  perhaps? You hardly need SO to find out whether there's a mac version of Flash.

Comment: I was able to find that but wanted to know if there was a cheaper option because $700 is a steep price to pay if i am just making a game for fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the opensource [Flex 4 SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4), then it would be free; however, if you use the [Adobe Flash](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash/) or [Adobe Flashbuilder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashbuilder/), then it will cost you lots of $$$ (much more than it is actually worth, I'd say). The tools all work on the Mac. I have the opensource Flex 4 SDK and Adobe Flash CS4 installed on my Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard computer. There were some minor things that needed to be fixed (I had to run `chmod a+x` on a few things that Adobe forgot to make executable, and attempting to alter the default install directory -- I originally tried using "/Developer/Applications" instead of the default "/Applications" -- makes the installation completely screw up), but other than that, everything has worked fine on Mac OS X.

As an aside, though, I would strongly recommend you take a look at [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) (see [A platform game written in HTML5](http://purplefloyd.wordpress.com/2009/09/11/a-platform-game-written-in-html5/) and [HTML5 Canvas Demos](http://www.canvasdemos.com/)) and [O3D](http://code.google.com/apis/o3d/) or [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) (if you want to make 3D games), if you are looking at developing web-based games. If you want to make games that run on the desktop, then I would suggest you take a look at [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) and [Panda3D](http://www.panda3d.org/) as alternative platforms for game development.

Comment: Google 03D API doesn't work on my mac my graphics card doesn't work with it, is there anything similar to it?

Comment: @mtwisterr, what kind of Mac do you have? How old is it? What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: @mtwisterr, you can look at WebGL as an alternative to O3D.

Comment: @mtwisterr, both O3D and WebGL are fairly new and experimental... but if you are just making 2D games, then HTML5's canvas should be just fine.

Comment: @Michael Aaron Safyan I have a mac book pro running os x 10.6.2 its less then a year old with a NVIDIA GeForce 9400M graphics card

Comment: HTML5 for web games right now? Does it even cover 50% of the market yet?

Comment: @Michael: For <50% of viewers, that's debatable. For >50% of viewers, it's clearly untrue.

Comment: @Michael, that's precisely my point. It's great, but it only runs in nightly builds of a single browser. By comparison the Flash port of quake requires Flash 9, which is on ~98% of mature market PCs.